# how to correctly use labeller in facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the plot below and I would like the facet plot labels to be what is in "lbl" =

```
> lbl
[1] "0% - 10%"  "10% - 20%"
```

How can labeller be added to the facet_wrap to get that text to show up and how does labeller correctly handle the ordering of that is output from the labeller function? i.e.  If I have 20 plots how does labeller correctly label the plots in the right order? Thank you.

here is the code:

```
x = c( rep(c(1,2,3,4,5),4)  )
group = c( rep(c(10,10,10,10,10),2),rep(c(20,20,20,20,20),2) )
lbl = paste0(  c("0%", paste0(   unique(group)[1:(length(unique(group))-1)]   ,"%" )  ) 
               ," - ",
               paste0(unique(group),"%"))
lbl
value = rnorm(20)
dat = data.frame( x= x , group  = group, value = value)
dat = dat %>% # create the mu, sd, q1 and q3 aggregates
  group_by(group,x)  %>%  
  summarise(mu =  round(mean(value),2), 
            sd= sqrt(round(sd(value),2)), 
            Q1 = quantile(value)[2],
            Q3 = quantile(value)[4],
            count = n())
dat
dat2 = dat %>%  gather (key = Metric, value= Value,c(mu, sd, Q1, Q3)) #melt the data
as.data.frame(dat2)
ggplot(data=dat2 , aes(x=x, y=Value, group = Metric,colour = Metric,linetype = Metric)) + 
  geom_line()  + geom_point() + ylab("value") + 
  xlab("v") + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c( seq(1,5,1)  ) ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c( seq(-3,3,.25)  )  ) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c(mu = "blue", sd = "blue", Q1 = "red", Q3 = "red")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values =c(mu = "dashed", sd= "solid", Q1 = "solid", Q3 = "solid"))  +
  facet_wrap(~ group, scales = "free",ncol=3) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size=10, angle=0),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size=12, face="bold"),
        strip.background = element_rect(colour="red", fill="#CCCCFF"))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to build a labeller; read `?labeller` and here, `?as_labeller` for help. All you really need to add is `labeller = as_labeller(setNames(lbl, sort(unique(group))))` (or a suitably named vector, constructed how you like) to `facet_wrap`:

```
ggplot(data=dat2 , aes(x=x, y=Value, group = Metric,colour = Metric,linetype = Metric)) + 
  geom_line()  + geom_point() + ylab("value") + 
  xlab("v") + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c( seq(1,5,1)  ) ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c( seq(-3,3,.25)  )  ) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c(mu = "blue", sd = "blue", Q1 = "red", Q3 = "red")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values =c(mu = "dashed", sd= "solid", Q1 = "solid", Q3 = "solid"))  +
  facet_wrap(~ group, scales = "free",ncol=3, 
      # add a labeller here:
      labeller = as_labeller(setNames(lbl, sort(unique(group))))) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size=10, angle=0),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size=12, face="bold"),
        strip.background = element_rect(colour="red", fill="#CCCCFF"))
```

[image: plot with proper facet labels]

Comment: but hows does setNames(lbl, unique(group) ) ensure that the order of the labels and the order of the plots are the same?

Comment: Just edited for that to add `sort`. It really doesn't matter how you build the named vector; normally you build the labels programmatically directly from the values, but here you already made a vector of labels, so I just used that.

Comment: I get an error when I run that Error in facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free", ncol = 3, labeller = as_labeller(setNames(lbl,  : 
  unused argument (labeller = as_labeller(setNames(lbl, sort(unique(group)))))

Comment: I can't reproduce that error. Copying in my code gives you that? Normally that error means something is in the wrong location.

Comment: Yes I get that when I replace the ggplot() with yours. Can you post your complete code including the lbl and everything?

Comment: Everything is already on the page; literally the only thing I changed was adding the labeller. What I didn't copy is the same as above; running what you posted and then what I posted is exactly what produced the plot in my answer.

Comment: autosense on the facet_wrap() function does not show a labeller parameter so I probably have an outdated version of ggplot 2?